# exponential random variable question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Let $X$ be an exponential random variable with parameter $\lambda=4$ and $Y$ be an exponential random variable with parameter $\lambda=5$. $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Find the probability that $3X<2Y$.

I'm thinking of first calculating the parameter for $3x$ and $2y$. Since $E(x)=1/4$, $E(3x)=3/4$, $\lambda(3x)=4/3$. Same thing to $Y$ and can get $\lambda(2y)=5/2$.

I think I should then integrate

$$\int_0^\infty P(3X>2Y\mid Y=y)\cdot\lambda(2y)\cdot e^{-\lambda(2y)\cdot y}\;dy$$

but I don't know how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The joint density function is $(4e^{-4x})(5e^{-5y})$ for $x$ and $y$ $\ge 0$, and $0$ elsewhere.

We want to integrate the joint density function over the part of the first quadrant made up of all points $(x,y)$ such that $3x<2y$.

So we want $y\gt \frac{3}{2}x$. Draw the line with equation $y=\frac{3}{2}x$. We are integrating over the part of the first quadrant that is **above** that line.

We integrate first with respect to $y$, from $y=\frac{3}{2}x$ to $\infty$. Then we integrate with respect to $x$, from $0$ to $\infty$. In symbols, we want
$$\int_0^\infty 4e^{-4x}\left(\int_{3x/2}^\infty 5e^{-5y}\,dy\right)\,dx.$$

The inner integral turns out to be $e^{-15x/2}$. The rest should not be hard to complete.

Comment: didn't expect it to be that simple! thank you

Comment: You are welcome. Fairly often the geometry points to a simple approach.